# implementing multiplication algorithm in java

Tags: java, algorithm, biginteger, multiplication

I have the following multiplication algorithm, that i am trying to implement using Java:

[image: Big Integer multiplication algorithm]

m: is the a number of digits

n: is the b number of digits

β: is the base

this is my java function that implments this algorithm:

```
public BigInteger prodbigbig(BigInteger a, BigInteger b, Integer base ){

        ArrayList<Integer> listA = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> listB  = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> listC = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int m = a.toString().length();
        int n = b.toString().length();
        Integer carry, temp;
        BigInteger result = BigInteger.ZERO;

        for(int i = 0; i < a.toString().length(); i++){
            listA.add(Character.getNumericValue( a.toString().charAt(i)));
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < b.toString().length(); i++){
            listB.add((Character.getNumericValue( b.toString().charAt(i))));
        }
        for(int i= 0; i <= m - 1; i++){
            listC.add(0);
        }

        for(int k = 0; k <= n - 1 ; k++) {
            carry = 0;
            for(int  i = 0; i <= m - 1; i++){
                temp = (listA.get(i) * listB.get(k)) + listC.get(i + k) + carry;
                listC.add(i+k,temp % base);
                carry = temp / base;
            }
            listC.add(k + m,carry);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < m + n; i++) {
            result = result.add(BigInteger.valueOf((long) (listC.get(i)*(Math.pow(base, i)))));
        }

        return result;
    }
```

but i don't know why i am not getting the correct result, until now i am not able to detect where it fails.

Comment: In addition to `set()` instead of  `add()` as per at least two answers, use `base` in conversion to and from digit - if using `String` as an intermediate representation at all, instead of `BigInteger.divideAndRemainder(base)`. In the declaration of the `List`s, do not use the implementation type. Use a pre-calculated length in the instantiations. Consider using arrays instead of `List`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem modifying my code in this way:

```
public BigInteger prodBigBig(BigInteger a, BigInteger b, int base ){

            BigInteger result = BigInteger.ZERO;

            if(a.compareTo(result) == 0 || b.compareTo(result) == 0)
                return result;

            int m = a.toString().length();
            int n = b.toString().length();
            int carry;
            int temp;
            ArrayList<Integer>listA = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<Integer>listB = new ArrayList<>();
            int[] listC = new int[m + n];

            for(int i = m - 1; i >= 0; i--){
                listA.add(Character.getNumericValue( a.toString().charAt(i)));
                listC[i] = 0;
            }

            for(int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                listB.add(Character.getNumericValue(b.toString().charAt(i)));
            }

            for(int k=0; k < n; k++) {
                carry = 0;
                for(int i = 0; i < m ; i++){
                    temp = (listA.get(i) * listB.get(k)) + listC[i + k] + carry;
                    listC[i + k] = temp % base;
                    carry = temp / base;
                }
                listC[k + m] = carry;
            }

            for(int i= 0; i < m + n; i++){
                result = result.add(BigInteger.valueOf((long) (listC[i] * Math.pow(base, i))));
            }
            return result;

    }
```

Comment: Assuming base > 1, how many product places does it take for `(long) (listC[i] * Math.pow(base, i))` not to be exact?

Answer (score 3):

```
listC.add(i+k,temp % base);
```

That should be

```
listC.set(i+k,temp % base);
```

and your final transformation to BigInteger will overflow with sufficiently large numbers. I would get rid of the `ArrayLists` altogether and use arrays of `int`, and then convert that to `byte[]` at the end and feed that directly to a constructor for `BigInteger.`

Answer (score 0):

It look like that you should use `set` instead of `add` in listC, because add(index, value), shift other element after index, but `set` replaced.

```
public BigInteger prodbigbig(BigInteger a, BigInteger b, Integer base ){

        ArrayList<Integer> listA = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> listB  = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> listC = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int m = a.toString().length();
        int n = b.toString().length();
        Integer carry, temp;
        BigInteger result = BigInteger.ZERO;

        for(int i = 0; i < a.toString().length(); i++){
            listA.add(Character.getNumericValue( a.toString().charAt(i)));
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < b.toString().length(); i++){
            listB.add((Character.getNumericValue( b.toString().charAt(i))));
        }
        for(int i= 0; i <= m - 1; i++){
            listC.add(0);
        }

        for(int k = 0; k <= n - 1 ; k++) {
            carry = 0;
            for(int  i = 0; i <= m - 1; i++){
                temp = (listA.get(i) * listB.get(k)) + listC.get(i + k) + carry;
                listC.set(i+k,temp % base);
                carry = temp / base;
            }
            listC.set(k + m,carry);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < m + n; i++) {
            result = result.add(BigInteger.valueOf((long) (listC.get(i)*(Math.pow(base, i)))));
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: I think `listC` should be the size of `n+m` and not just `m`